# How to load dialog box before refreshing/leaving page in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dialog, vuetify.js, addeventlistener

I am working on a form and I want to ask the user if they want to submit their progress before they leave the page. I'm using vue js and vuetify:

```
            <v-dialog
                v-model="showExitDialog"
            >
                <v-card>
                    <v-card-title>Do you want to submit?</v-card-title>
                    <v-card-actions>
                        <v-spacer/>
                        <v-btn @click="submit">Yes</v-btn>
                        <v-btn @click="showExitDialog = false">No</v-btn>
                    </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
            </v-dialog>
```

'showExitDialog: false' is what is written in data

My current function looks like this inside of the created hook:

```
created() {
    document.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) { 
        this.showExitDialog = true;
    });
    console.log('1234567890');
},
```

It doesn't bring up the dialog box at all but the log function actually logs to the console and I can't quite tell how to fix it as there are no errors.

How can I make it so that the v-dialog is shown once a page refreshes/once the user leaves a page?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use something like:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event)
{
    //here display modal with app.showModal = true
};
```

*This will be outside of vue